# png files not displaying in IE

Tags: css

hello
can someone tell me why this css does not display png in IE? many thanks

```
#header
    {
        width:1004px;
        height:309px;
        float: left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        background-image::url(../images/header.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: You have a double colon in `background-image::url`

Comment: So are you sure this is a png specific problem? Have you tried subtituteing a different image?

Comment: @grantk it is just png and only from the server side. using wamp they are fine. on the server in have gd enabled and png enable.

Comment: What do you mean, "using wamp they are fine"? Do they work in IE if you use another server?

Comment: Also, have you tried substituting a different image?

Comment: @ploppy:  There are so many problems with the question itself.  It would have been nice to have all the information included in the original post.  Does this code work in non-IE browsers?  The double colon is a syntax problem and if it's not part of the working code, should be fixed or mentioned in the question.  Has an absolute URL for the PNG been tried yet?  Can the direct URL to the PNG be called up in a browser all by itself?  Can you see PNGs on other pages or in other parts of the code?  Explain what you mean by _"using wamp they are fine"_ and add it to the question.  Etc...

Answer (score 2):

There is a double colon in `::url`

Try this:

```
#header
    {
        width:1004px;
        height:309px;
        float: left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        background-image:url(../images/header.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: sorry i was aware of the double colon and should have removed before posting. so that is not the problem. thanks

Comment: An explanation about the double colon would have been nice in the answer as well.

Comment: i was informed that for IE you have to put imageheight and itemwidth? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use firebug on firefox to see where the problem is, i'm assuming since you're aware of the double colon issue this may not be on your stylesheet so the problem maybe in the image file path, put in consideration where the css file is, if in sperate folder you might need to use a couple more of "../" to get back to the root where the page is and call the image in the css relatively